# reassigning JList & JComboBox data

Tags: java, swing

I've been looking through the Java API, but have had no luck in working this out. After you initiate a JList, is there any way to replace, or reload the 'data' string? I've also been looking to do the same thing with a JComboBox.

```
String[] data = {"one", "two", "three", "four"};
JList dataList = new JList(data);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using one of the utility constructors for JList, which takes an array.  The List is backed by a ListModel.  The utility constructor uses the following to create an implementation of an AbstractListModel:

```
new AbstractListModel() {
            public int getSize() { return listData.length; }
            public Object getElementAt(int i) { return listData[i]; }
}
```

where `listData` would be your `data` set.  You can do the same and pass it into `dataList.setModel()`.  You might be best served, if this is for more than just a prototype, by creating your own, full-blown implementation of ListModel.

For reference, here is the [JList tutorial from Sun](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html).

JComboBox is a bit simpler, as the `DefaultComboBoxModel` class has a constructor that takes an array of `Object` as a parameter.  To replace the data there, you can simply call:

```
 myComboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(data));
```

Comment: thanks akf. That makes things a little clearer. I've been looking for how to replace the array ...

Answer (score 2):

The list data is stored in a ListModel (Accessable via the get/set Model methods).  You simply need to create a new ListModel (Well, an implementation of a ListModel) and pass it to the JList using its setModel method.

Comment: How come it is set with a string initially then?